# Microsoft Graph API change notification delay in local testenvironment

Tags: azure, network-programming, microsoft-graph-api, ngrok, change-notification

**Question**
Does MsGraph give a lower priority to change notifications when running a subscribed webhook locally? If not, I'm open to hearing any theories as to why this extra delay (from MsGraph to the webhook) could be happening on the local machine, but not when running it in their cloud.

**Some background info**
When running an Azure Function webhook locally through ngrok (reverse proxy), there's considerable delay in MsGraph sending change notifications to the webhook. Once ngrok receives a notification, it's passed on almost instantly to the correct API call. Calling the ngrok url manually has an near-instant response time. The problem is in Microsoft Graph not sending the notification updates at all (or tens of minutes to hours later).

Forging my own change notifications and feeding them to an Azure Queue for now, but I'd rather just receive live updates to properly test the different paths.

I'm subscribing to the 'messages' change notifications.

Edit: One could work around the delay by forging notifications and manually feeding them to a queue.

Comment: Which resource have you subscribed to? There is a [latency doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#latency) for different resources.

Comment: Message, which is marked unknown for both average and max latency in that table. Good to know, but I'm still wondering why the messages are near instant when running live as opposed to the extreme delays I'm experiencing when running local.

Comment: Is this issue still happening for you? If it is near instant in cloud then may be your local setup has some latency.

Comment: Yes, it is. If it's the local setup, then wouldn't all other calls to the same API also experience latency? This isn't the case, and direct communication to the MsGraph API and my API is fast: it's only the delay in change notifications that's causing trouble. All other calls with my API or with MsGraph is near instant, whether live or local.